# Hide a control method from Intellisense?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls, intellisense

I have a ListView user control where I've implemented the known `AddItem` `RemoveItem` procedures as this:

```
Public Function AddItem(ByVal Item As ListViewItem) As ListViewItem

    RaiseEvent ItemAdded(Me, New ItemAddedEventArgs With { _
                             .Item = Item
                       })

    Return MyBase.Items.Add(Item)

End Function
```

Then I want to hide (or fully remove in any way) the native method `Listview.Items.Add()` from intellisense or from the control itself to only display my `AddItem` method instead of `Items.Add`.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try shadowing the Items collection and then apply attributes to hide it:

```
<Browsable(False), _
 EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> _
Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Items As ListViewItemCollection
  Get
    Return MyBase.Items
  End Get
End Property
```

Comment: thankyou but If I do that then the "Items" member is hided, I wanted to hide only "Items.Add" but not "Items".

Comment: @ElektroStudios Hmm, that would almost require replacing the ListViewItemCollection class inside the ListView control.  I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

While it would not hide the `Add` and `Remove` methods from Intellisense, you could use the [AsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function to make sure the list is exposed as a [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will prevent using the `Add` or `Remove` methods by throwing a `NotSupportedException`, so it will force the developer to use your `AddItem` and `RemoveItem` methods.